# How to pass $(this) to the callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is an example that works fine

```js
$(".multi-select").change(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().addClass("glow");
} );
```

```css
.glow {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slides-containter">
  <div class="slide-container" id="slide_34">
    <div class="zoom-container">
      <span class="zoom-caption">
        <h3>
          <input class="multi-select" id="slide_select_34" name="ids[]" type="checkbox" value="34" />
        </h3>
      </span>
      <img alt="4c730521b21310758a4809d7b56feec5" src="http://foobar.tuxpartei.ch/foobar.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

But for some reason it doesn't work if I try to split it to some callback function like

```js
function glow_it() {
 $(this).parent().parent().addClass("glow");
};


$(".multi-select").change(function() {
 glow_it();   
}
```

```css
.glow {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slides-containter">
  <div class="slide-container" id="slide_34">
    <div class="zoom-container">
      <span class="zoom-caption">
        <h3>
          <input class="multi-select" id="slide_select_34" name="ids[]" type="checkbox" value="34" />
        </h3>
      </span>
      <img alt="4c730521b21310758a4809d7b56feec5" src="http://foobar.tuxpartei.ch/foobar.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

I suppose I should pass this somehow to it. How it should be done ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Include code in question please.

Comment: `$(".multi-select").on('change', glow_it);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because when you're calling the `glow_it()` function, the **context** of the selector is lost, i.e. `$(this)` is no longer referring to the element where the `change` event is fired, but it is referring to the window object instead, i.e. `$(window)`. To resolve this, pass `$(this)` as a variable to the function:

```
function glow_it(t) {
    $(t).parent().parent().addClass("oxo");
};

$(".multi-select").change(function() {
    glow_it(this);   
});
```

p/s: You also have a syntax error, because you left out the closing parenthesis `)` on the last line in your `.change()` event.

See proof-of-concept fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/h0euqvf0/7/

---

**Update**: Alternatively you can call the `glow_it()` function as a second parameter in `.on('change', [handler])` so as to preserve the context, as suggested by [@adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) in his comment:

```
$(".multi-select").on('change', glow_it);
```

The explanation to why this works is quite well explained in the jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation:

> When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the
>   element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events
>   this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated
>   events this is an element matching `selector`. (Note that `this` may
>   not be equal to `event.target` if the event has bubbled from a
>   descendant element.) To create a jQuery object from the element so
>   that it can be used with jQuery methods, use `$( this )`.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h0euqvf0/5/

Comment: Nice. And alternately, there's `.apply`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your $(this) in var and pass as parameter.

```
function glow_it(multiSelect ) {
     multiSelect.parent().parent().addClass("oxo");
    };


    $(".multi-select").change(function() {
    var multiSelect = $(this);
     glow_it(multiSelect );   
    )};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use jquery [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) method. It allows you to define a call context. In this particular case is a little useless since you may use `glow_it` as `change` handler but it may worth to present this option for some other scenario where this firs better

```
$(".multi-select").change(function() {
    $.proxy(glow_it, this)();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Terry's answer, you can also use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to define the value of `this` when calling a function.

```
function glow_it() {
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("glow");
}

$(".multi-select").on('change', function () {
    glow_it.call($(this));   
});
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/faeha2vk/)

Also, instead of using `.parent().parent()`, i'd suggest using `.closest('h3')`:

```
function glow_it() {
    $(this).closest('h3').addClass("glow");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do either of the following :

**Specify `glow_it` as a named handler** (preferred)

```
$(".multi-select").change(glow_it);
```

Here, the event object is automatically passed to the named handler in the same way it would be passed to an anonymous handler.

**Call `glow_it` from an anonymous handler in such a way that it is informed of `this`.**

```
$(".multi-select").change(function(e) {
    glow_it.call(this, e);   
}
```

It's good to get into the habit of passing the event object `e` even if it's not used. One day you will be glad of it.